# Kernel Threads vs Hyperthreads

Tags: multithreading, operating-system, kernel, hyperthreading

What is the difference between kernel threads and hyper-threads? Or they are same?

I understand that it the kernel threads that os schedules not the user threads.

Seen nobody talking about both of them same time......

Comment: Kernel threads: software. Hhyper-threads, hardware. Alternatively, different types of fruit.

Answer (score 2):

"Kernel threads" are software threads created and scheduled by the kernel. Compare user threads, which are created by user-mode libraries and are one thread of execution as far as the kernel is concerned.

"Hyperthreading" is intel's marketing name for simultaneous multithreading, a hardware multithreading solution for superscalar machines. Essentially it lets a CPU (core) fetch and execute instructions from multiple (2 in intel's case) memory locations simultaneously. This is called "thread-level parallelism", i.e. increasing the utilisation of CPU by running multiple tasks.

A hyperthreading CPU (e.g. an i7 core) presents multiple CPUs to the OS kernel, and at any point in time the kernel can execute one software thread on each of them. Usually it also tells the OS which "CPUs" are hardware threads of a single CPU so the scheduler can make better decisions.